# Hints for each choice in dropdown menu

Tags: orbeon

I would like to add a hint to each choice in dropdown menu. Is that possible?
Like in radio buttons, there are three fields: Label, Value, Hint. In dropdown menu there are only Label and Value.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't overlook anything: this isn't possible out-of-the-box. If you need to provide hints for individual items, then I'd recommend you use checkboxes or radio buttons, as appropriate.